# iOS - UIWebView refresh issue on slow/lossy connections

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

Hey guys I am new to the iOS world so please bear with me.

I created a webview in order to make a web app native to iOS and the app is currently on the store.
However some users have experienced issues reloading the view (in the alert message) on lossy/slow connections. I tested it out with the 'network link conditioner' tools and on slow connections the alert keeps popping even when you try refreshing the page.
Below is my code, hoping you can help me fix the issue.

```
//Overide the default error message by adding error handling mecanism
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                message:@"You must be connected to the internet to use HIPPOmsg. Try again or click the home button to quit"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Try again"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}

//Implement the 'Try again' button action
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://app.hippomsg.com/home.php"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [webView loadRequest:req];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You alert has only 1 button, and u have a method definition set to that button. 
So obviously every time u click the alert button, UIAlerview delegate will be called and it will keep trying again and again (until ur internet actually works).

So provide 2 buttons as per u alert message, "Try Again" and "Home". So "Try Again" will perform ur method wat u have given, "Home" wills top searching and quit the process.